# Google Places API Autocomplete Error when enable minify

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using the new google-places api, calling the autocompleteactivity intent from a fragment, the autocomplete can't load any results when I set minifyEnabled to true in the gradle file. It does working if set the properties to false. Need help. Thanks.

```java
try {
                        /*
                         * Initialize Places
                         */
                        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "initialized places api");
                            Places.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    getResources().getString(R.string.places_api_key));
                        }

                        // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
                        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID,
                                Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);

                        // Start the autocomplete intent.
                        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                                AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                                .build(getActivity());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_PLACE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
                    }
```

When check back the logcat, I get this kind of message: "Error while autocompleting: ERROR"

Comment: Please post your full logcat's stack trace and your build.gradle. Also double check that you've added your API key in your release build's manifest (and that it's properly restricted using your release certificate).